# Is there a limit to # of users connected to a screen

Tags: gnu-screen, multiuser

When using screen -x NAME is there a max number of connections to a single screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of users *logged in* on a Linux system is limited by the number of available pseudo terminals.  The maximum number of these is found in `/proc/sys/kernel/pty/max` (4096 on my test machine).

This would be an upper limit to how many users would be able to give the `screen -x` command.

On non-Linux systems, the limit would also be set by the maximum number of allowed concurrent users. On NetBSD and OpenBSD, pseudo terminals may be created up to a limit of 992.